# Nodejs async.each wait for first loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to process rowsArr (lets say 100 records) asynchronous but I want to load country list from database only one time to avoid database connections. I am trying below example code but it is opening database connections 100 times.

```
var countryList = null;

async.each(rowsArr, function(row, callback) {


    if( countryList == null )
    {
        console.log("open database here to get country list and then assign to below variable");

        countryList = countriesFromDatabase;

        callback( countryList );
    }
    else
    {
        callback( countryList );
    }


}, function(err){

      console.log("all rows are processed");

});
```

It is working fine with **async.eachSeries** but I want it in asynchronous manner. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get Countries from database
2. Process all rows

So following will work

```
function getCountries(callback) {
  console.log("open database here to get country list and then assign to below variable");
  callback(null,countriesFromDatabase);
}
getCountries(function(err, countriesFromDatabase) {
 // use countries in following async loop
  async.each(rowsArr, function(row, callback) {
    callback(null, row); //process row here
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("all rows are processed");
  });
});
```

Comment: this approach is good but my above function is already inside another loop. So 100 records are to process in one loop and there are millions of records.

Comment: I'm assuming until you get `countriesFromDatabase` you can not process `row`, so still if I get `countriesFromDatabase` in first iteration, other rows will not have `countriesFromDatabase`(being asynchronous)
So my guess u need to change function a bit

Comment: This is almost certainly the right answer to the question as posted.  I'd either edit the question to reflect why this answer doesn't work, or accept it.

Comment: I will change my code logic as per giving suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does what it should actually, all hundred rows processing starts at the same time and they're passing the if block.

You might want to use locks. https://github.com/BorisKozo/node-async-locks

That way you can lock your countryList checking process to avoid multiple database connections.